# Understanding もういいかげん、このままならずに済む

Tags: reading-comprehension

The family is talking about getting appendicitis. Grandad says:

> 「わしもこの年になってもならなかったんじゃ。もういいかげん、このままならずに済むじゃろ。」
> I also couldn't help getting it this year. ?????

I'm a bit stuck on the rest.
I think verb-ずに済む or verb-ないで済む means "don't have to verb". Is that right?

I know もういい and いいかげんにしろ are along the lines of "that's enough!", "quit it!".

But I can't make any sense of it when I try to put it all together:

> That's enough. You don't have to get it as it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The "この年" refers to his (old) age, not the current year. "この年になっても" → "even though I've reached this age"
- The "ならなかった" means "[盲腸炎(appendicitis)(?)に]ならなかった" ("never got appendicitis").
- もういいかげん here means something like "at this rate".
- このまま indicates continuation of the status quo.
- For "verb-ずに済む", "be spared from verb-ing" or "go with out verbing/having to verb" may be better.

> Even at my old age, I've never got appendicitis. At this rate, I should be able to continue to go without getting it.