# 確かにお金はかかるけど、それより行きも帰りも大きい荷物持って歩かなくて済むから・・・

Tags: meaning

> 確かにお金はかかるけど、それより行きも帰りも大きい荷物持って歩かなくて済むから・・・

Can someone explain what the the 済む means at the end of this sentence?
My thoughts are it means something is finished.

"Sure it costs money but on the other hand, I have to go and come carrying this big bag, if I don't have to walk then I am finished?"

Comment: Are you sure it's not 「持って歩**か**なくて済む」?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40685 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23903

Comment: The latter half of your sentence means "I don't have to carry large baggage while walking around". See [JLPT N2 Grammar: なくて済む](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6%E6%B8%88%E3%82%80-nakute-sumu-meaning/)

Comment: Oh thanks, I am studying N3, hence why I don't know it yet...